# Responsive design: 2 columns of posts, 1 query, sorted by css

Tags: css, sorting

I'm building a wordpress theme. The posts are queried and display in order of date published, descending, eg:

```
post6
post5
post4
post3
post2
post1
```

What I want to do is sort these posts into 2 columns, based on their category, but maintain date order. Eg:

```
Category1 | Category2
post6     | post5
post3     | post4
          | post2
          | post1
```

I am aware that I can do 2 separate queries but I DON'T want to do that.

In the interest of responsive design, if I resize the window to a mobile device, I want all posts to be back in date order (see top), hence the single query.

Is there a way to achieve the sorting (left & right) just with CSS?

I've tried just floating, or position absolute but neither achieve the sort correctly.

This isn't necessarily a WordPress question as the data could come from any source.

Comment: CSS can't style based on element content. You'd need to add some information in the generated HTML for the CSS to understand. Such as category names as classes, then use media queries to work on those.

Comment: Agreed, so when parsing the query I would have applied classes based on category. But it's the actual formatting of the elements that I get stuck on.

Comment: This question needs far more information to be answerable. What does your markup look like, for starters?

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is to make sure each post is output inside a dedicated element while assigning the current post category as that element's class

Use CSS to separate them out based on categories classes

Comment: And how would I go about separating them using css? That's the bit I'm stuck on. I understand defining classes based on category. Cheers.

Comment: Think of it this way: CSS is used to add styles to existing elements, while php is used to generate the HTML DOM structure - it can conditionally create the elements that you can then style using the CSS. So doing this with "CSS only" is not going to be possible unless you generate appropriate elements for the CSS to deal with.

Comment: You can follow my example and output everything into a parent div, then, since you only have two categories, you can add css styles based on categories to float left or right within the parent div.

Comment: Also keep in mind, once the page has been parsed and sent to the client, you'll need some javascript to detect user interactions such as resizing the window, so you can switch the classes assigned to the elements to move the content around. At this point, the server has already processed the php, generated the html dom structure, sent the html and css to the client and now the client takes over in terms of what is happening. SO if the client resizes the window the server has no way of seeing that (unless you communicate that back which I don't recommend in your situation)

Comment: But if you are only concerned with mobile or not mobile, with wordpress (php), you can use the if(wp_is_mobile()) {...} else{...} conditional to detect whether it is a mobile device making a request to see the page. Then you can output the apporpriate HTML elements that will allow for a view in two columns vs one column.